# Data Families and Typeable

Tags: haskell

Following is a perfectly compilable code:

```
data family DF a
data instance DF Int = DFInt deriving (Show)
data instance DF Char = DFChar deriving (Show)
```

However trying to derive `Typeable` as in the following gives a "Duplicate instance declarations" error:

```
data family DF a
data instance DF Int = DFInt deriving (Typeable)
data instance DF Char = DFChar deriving (Typeable)
```

So, how to derive `Typeable` for data families? Is it possible at all? If not then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the output of the derivations using `-ddump-deriv` you see that each of the data family instance declarations was producing an identical `instance Typeable1 DF`.

```
data family DF a
data instance DF Int = DFInt deriving (Typeable)
data instance DF Char = DFChar deriving (Typeable)
```

gives

```
instance Data.Typeable.Internal.Typeable1 Main.DF where
  Data.Typeable.Internal.typeOf1 _
    = Data.Typeable.Internal.mkTyConApp
        (Data.Typeable.Internal.mkTyCon
           17188516606402618172## 4748486123618388125## "main" "Main" "DF")
        []

instance Data.Typeable.Internal.Typeable1 Main.DF where
  Data.Typeable.Internal.typeOf1 _
    = Data.Typeable.Internal.mkTyConApp
        (Data.Typeable.Internal.mkTyCon
           17188516606402618172## 4748486123618388125## "main" "Main" "DF")
        []
```

So this type derivation isn't really doing what you want it to do--it's deriving the family as `Typeable1` not the instances. But then, likely what you need since `instance (Typeable1 s, Typeable a) => Typeable (s a)` is built-in.

```
data family DF a
deriving instance Typeable1 DF
data instance DF Int = DFInt deriving (Show)
data instance DF Char = DFChar deriving (Show)

data DFAll = forall a . Typeable a => DFAll (DF a)

toDFA :: Typeable a => DF a -> DFAll
toDFA = DFAll

fromDFA :: Typeable a => DFAll -> Maybe (DF a)
fromDFA (DFAll x) = cast x
```

and

```
*Main> fromDFA (toDFA DFInt) :: Maybe (DF Int)
Just DFInt
```

Comment: So the instance derivation problem looks like a bug. Concerning your answer, what exactly did you introduce the existential for?

Comment: Just to demonstrate that you get a functioning `cast` out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a standalone deriving `Typeable1` instance, as in the following code, has solved the problem, but I have no explanation as to why this works, so the question remains open.

```
data family DF a
deriving instance Typeable1 DF
data instance DF Int = DFInt deriving (Show)
data instance DF Char = DFChar deriving (Show)
```